# TypeError: object with buffer protocol required - trying to write to SMBus

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, smbus

I'm using a raspberry pi pico to read data from a SHT3x sensor using the I2C protocol. I'm quite new to (micro)python so I used [this example](http://www.pibits.net/code/raspberry-pi-sht31-sensor-example.php). This example is for a regular Raspberry Pi since I didn't find any for the Pico. However, the SMBus library is not found. I assume it is just not available for micropython (I have version 1.17).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: no module named 'smbus'
```

There seems to be only one micropython wrapper for SMBus (as far as I found), [this one](https://github.com/gkluoe/micropython-smbus). When I use this wrapper, the problem I have and don't understand is the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in <module>
  File "usmbus.py", line 50, in write_i2c_block_data
TypeError: object with buffer protocol required
```

Refering to this line function: `writeto_mem(addr, register, data)` ([documentation](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.I2C.html#machine.I2C.writeto_mem)).
The data that I pass in is as follows

```
addr = 0x44
register = 0x2C
data = [0x06]
```

I understood that it has something to do with framebuffer in micropython not being supported, but I don't understand how to fix it. Can someone help me out? Or suggest me other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If the sensor supports I2C, you should be able to use the [builtin MicroPython I2C support](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.I2C.html).

I also found a [library for the SHT3x](https://github.com/micropython-Chinese-Community/mpy-lib/tree/master/sensor/SHT3x/I2C_16bit), by searching on the [MicroPython forum](https://forum.micropython.org/index.php).